# Spinrdf sp:now function is not returning anything

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, rules

> SPIN is a way to represent a wide range of business rules.

This is the official one line description for spin (`spinrdf`).
Spin enables users to represent their rules with sparqls in ontologies.

I needed to make these descriptions since there is no spinrdf tag.

I have been using spin about a week to write some rules. Now I'm writing some functions to simplify my sparqls in my rules. I have a written a simple date comparison function `compareDates`. When I call the function with the following sparql there is no errors and gives the expected result.

```
SELECT ?result
WHERE {
 BIND(:compareDates("2015-03-03"^^xsd:date, "2015-06-09"^^xsd:date) as ?result)
}
```

I would like to use `sp:now` function comes with spin. When I use the following sparql I have no output.

```
SELECT ?result
WHERE {
 BIND(:compareDates("2015-03-03"^^xsd:date, sp:now()) as ?result)
}
```

Then I tried the following, but no luck:

```
SELECT ?result
WHERE {
 BIND(sp:now() as ?now)
 BIND(:compareDates("2015-03-03"^^xsd:date, ?now) as ?result)
}
```

And then I decided to see what sp:now returns and I have runned the following sparql the result is null. This lead me to a conclusion that I won't be able to run this function.

```
SELECT ?now
WHERE {
 BIND(sp:now() as ?now)
}
```

I would like to use that function or similar one but I don't get the problem. Any comment is appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

As shown in the following screenshot, the function does not contain any body! This would be the problem but, why it's been placed in the related ontology if won't work.

[image: sp:now Function form in topBraid Composer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I have find out two alternative methods for having now datetime. In fact there exists a sparql implementaion of `now()` function documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-now).

```
SELECT ?now
WHERE {
    BIND(now() as ?now).
}
```

This sparql will return the following:

```
[now]
2015-03-24T22:12:29.183+02:00
```

There is an alternative method placed in spin ontology; `afn:now()` which is placed under `spl:MiscFunctions` class. This function will give the same result.

By the way, I have been using `xsd:date` as my functions argument but the both now function alternatives returns `xsd:dateTime` literals. 
To convert these to `xsd:date` is another story. 
There exists some cast functions but they convert only type but not trim the hour part of the `xsd:dateTime` which causes my comparison to fail. 
Thus have come up with the following sparql which uses an indirect approach to convert `xsd:dateTime` to `xsd:date` :

```
SELECT ?nowDateTime ?nowDate 
WHERE {
 BIND(now() as ?nowDateTime). 
 BIND(spif:cast(spif:dateFormat(?nowDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd"), xsd:date) as ?nowDate).
}
```

Which converted the successfully. 
This could be a premature way to convert between to date literal types but this is what I have came up to solve my problem. 
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Also note that you can `select (now() as ?nowDateTime) ...`if you don't need the value in the query.  You don't have to use `bind`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It's been useful for me.